# Initialize Enum with only one case via rawValue

Tags: swift, enums

I am developing off of a contract and we have a message that contains an enumeration but it only has one possible value.  In order to future proof I wanted to make sure I used an enum so that any additional values that might be added wouldn't require a lot of work.  So I did this:

```
enum MyEnumeration: String {
    case Case1 = "ValueFromContract"
}
```

And when I am reading the message I tried to initialize my enum like so:

```
let myEnum = MyEnumeration(rawValue: "ValueFromContract")
```

myEnum is then set to the value Some, which is obviously not what I want.  I am developing on Xcode 6.1.1 and this may not be an issue in later versions of Swift.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you cannot initialize by rawValue if the enum only have one case.  So I had to do this:

```
enum MyEnumeration: String {
    case Case1 = "ValueFromContract"
    case Unknown = "Unknown"
}
```

Then the rawValue initializer worked just fine:

```
let myEnum = MyEnumeration(rawValue: "ValueFromContract")
```

Not sure if its by design, but its good to know...

Answer (score 0):

I'm having no difficulty creating your enum with a single value with Xcode 6.1.1:

```
enum MyEnumeration: String {
    case Case1 = "ValueFromContract"
}
```

Note that `MyEnumeration(rawValue: "ValueFromContract")` returns an optional since the string you pass might not be a valid rawValue for that enum.  You have to unwrap that optional to use it.  Here I'm using optional binding:

```
if let myEnum = MyEnumeration(rawValue: "ValueFromContract") {
    if myEnum == .Case1 {
        println("\(myEnum.rawValue)")  // This does print "ValueFromContract"
    }
}
```

Comment: Strange, maybe there is something else preventing it, but it will not work for me unless I have multiple cases.

Answer (score 0):

Either you write

```
let myEnum = MyEnumeration(rawValue: "ValueFromContract")!
```

or

```
let myEnum: MyEnumeration = .Case1
```

Anyhow I don't see much sense in an enumeration with only one value.